# process-resources and process-test-resources in one command

Tags: maven

Hi I want to run the following phases:

```
mvn process-resources
mvn process-test-resources
```

Is there a way to do it without calling both phases separately?

Comment: Just simply use `mvn package`... that contains bother plus several other steps which are already mentioned in the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven execute phases one after each other. Executing `process-test-resources` also executes `process-resources` previously.

Maven **Default Lifecycle** order

- validate
- initialize
- generate-sources
- `process-sources`
- generate-resources
- process-resources
- compile
- process-classes
- generate-test-sources
- `process-test-sources`
- ...

You can check more about this at [Lifecycle reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-reference)